# how to use proguard toothpick rule?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-proguard, sbt-proguard, toothpick-di

I am using TP in my project.
And I am Injecting some objects using TP. But when I applied the proguard rule in my application. It is working fine with debug mode But give null objects in release mode all the Objects I have injected through the @Inject annotations.

Comment: There is not enough details to help you. At least, your proguard block should be added.  Did you try this? https://github.com/stephanenicolas/toothpick/issues/146

Comment: I have tried this already. But didnt worked for me.@Snicolas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this working in our project, beyond what was in Issue #146, you need to add a few more things.  There is an @Keep annotation setting from the android support annotations library that can be used to mark a class not to be obfuscated, I've had to do this on some kotlin data classes as Retrofit and the kotlin-reflect library couldn't play nice with the obfuscation.   Anyways, the gist can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/kingargyle/e23fcab92922f7c95347fe25a5b28094).   In addition, you may want to specifically tell it to not obfuscate anything in the generated FactoryRegistry class in the package you told toothpick to generate the non-reflection registry and factory implementations.

```
    # Note that if we could use kapt to generate registries, possible to get rid of this
-keepattributes Annotation
# Do not obfuscate classes with Injected Constructors
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @javax.inject.Inject (...);
}
# Do not obfuscate classes with Injected Fields
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @javax.inject.Inject ;
}
# Do not obfuscate classes with Injected Methods
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @javax.inject.Inject ;
}
-keep @android.support.annotation.Keep class *
-keep @javax.inject.Singleton class *
-dontwarn javax.inject.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-keep class **$$Factory { *; }
-keep class **$$MemberInjector { *; }

-adaptclassstrings
-keep class toothpick.** { *; }
```

Comment: Almost 90% of my classes are classes with some type of injections. Another 10% - model classes that should not be obfuscated because of Retrofit and Gson. It looks like it is simpler to just add -dontobfuscate for Proguard config... But I don't like this solution.